# Autowire/inject scoped bean into controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, autowired

Spring 3.2. Everything works when I do:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Inject
    Provider<MyBean> provider;

    @RequestMapping("/chart")
    public void getChart(HttpServletResponse resp) {
        provider.get();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work when I set MyBean as an argument to getChart:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/chart")
    public void getChart(HttpServletResponse resp, MyBean myBean) {
        // No such method MyBean.<init>()
    }
}
```

So Spring tries to create a new instance of myBean instead of using already bound one.

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Inject
    @Bean @Scope("request")
    public MyBean provideMyBean(MyOtherBean myOtherBean) {
         return myOtherBean.getMyBean();
    }
}
```

It also doesn't work if I make my controller request scoped, and add @Inject/@Autowired to the `getChart()`. Then it cannot find HttpServletResponse instance (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException), although there surely must be one in request-scope.

Maybe it just isn't implemented in Spring?

Comment: Are you trying to databind MyBean or just get an instance from the IOC container?

Comment: Where is the mybean declared?

Comment: @KevinBowersox just get an instance.

Comment: @Krishna in the last code snippet, provideMyBean().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by creating a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver:

```
/**
 * Resolves beans defined in {@link Config},
 * because Spring doesn't want to do it implicitly.
 *
 * Makes possible to write something like
 * @RequestMapping(value="/chart", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 * getChart(HttpServletRequest req, MyBean myBean)
 *
 * and Spring will inject both arguments.
 */
public class MethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, BeanFactoryAware {
    private final Set<Class> knownTypes = Config.getDeclaredTypes();

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        Class<?> type = parameter.getParameterType();
        return knownTypes.contains(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
            MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        Class<?> type = parameter.getParameterType();
        return beanFactory.getBean(type);
    }
}
```

and in Config:

```
static Set<Class> getDeclaredTypes() {
    Set<Class> result = Sets.newHashSet();
    Method[] methods = Config.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getAnnotation(Bean.class) != null) {
            result.add(method.getReturnType());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is quite a javascript-ish way to go... The preferred way with Spring would be to @Inject your dependency as a property of your Controller. The scope is achieved via a proxy-based mechanism, so don't be afraid of any thread-safety issue.

Comment: You're right about property of Controller. Actually, over some time of actively using dependency injection, we see less and less need in this MethodArgumentResolver, because now our Controllers methods require much less dependencies than before, so no need in custom beans in parameters.

Comment: But I don't agree about proxy-based beans. I'd rather use Provider<> to be explicit about scopes. Scopes are important.